# Trying to save data to a collection with mongoDB, nodejs and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't seem to figure out how to save a document to a collection using mongoDB, mongoose and nodejs. I'm trying to save some data that I am returning from an API to a collection that I have made in mongodb atlas, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that.

I've tried making a  schema with mongoose, and tried saving through that and tried directly connecting to the db but nothing I do seems to work.

Here is my schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const twitterStateDataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  stateName: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('TwitterStateData', twitterStateDataSchema);
```

Here is my call to the Schema:

```
TwitterStateData.insertOne(statesMap).then(test => {
  console.log(test);
})
```

Here is my connection to the db:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB)
.then(() => {
  console.log('Connected to Sport Stakehouse database!')
})
.catch(() => {
  console.log('Connection Failed!')
})
```

and here is what is in my env.json minus the secret stuff:

```
.mongodb.net/gameData?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I'm trying to send this object:

```
{ IA: 4, undefined: 7, MI: 1, FL: 1, WV: 1, TX: 1, MN: 1, MO: 1 }
```

I'm getting the error insertOne() is not a function but I don't think that is my problem here.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents), you might use `.create` or `.save`. The `.save()` is a method coming from the Model instance, and the `.create()` is called directly from the Model as a method call, use according to your needs.

Using create:

```
const data = { IA: 4, undefined: 7, MI: 1, FL: 1, WV: 1, TX: 1, MN: 1, MO: 1 };
TwitterStateData.create(data, function (err, small) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // saved!
});
```

Using save:

```
const object = new TwitterStateData(yourData);
object.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});
```

**Note:** You need a connection open in order to the functions work.

Comment: This seems to add a new collection called twitterstatedatas, not sure what's happening here. It doesn't add any data to the collection only the collection itself.

Comment: So it's actually adding to the correct collection but also creating another one called twitterstatedatas for some reason.

Comment: If you use `.create` will create another collection. If you have an instance of your collection, use the `.save` method.